# Field name for stats to be calculated not appearing using v.vect.stats

Tags: qgis, spatial-statistics, grass-7.0, qgis-grass-plugin

I'm trying to calculate the average value for an attribute of a set of points that fall within a set of polygons using `v.vect.stats` from GRASS. I've checked the attribute table of the point layer which looks like this:

[image]

But in the dialogue for `v.vect.stats` I'm only able to see a subset of these fields:

[image]

Why is it that I can't select the `Area (ha)` field here? Is there any workaround to be able to select this field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Area (ha)` field is string because it is left aligned in the attribute table. You should convert into a numeric one.

Open "Field Calculator" to create a new `Area` field. Select `Decimal number (real)`. Use  `to_real( "Area (ha)" )` expression like this:

[image]

Then, you will see `Area` field in the tool options.

Comment: This answers the question and I'm now able to select the column and run the algorithm. For some reason it is giving NULL for all polygons but that is a separate question which I've asked here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/410774/68671