# GRASS QGIS v.vect.stats returns NULL for all polygons

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, spatial-statistics, null

I'm running `v.vect.stats` from Grass using the processing toolbox in QGIS to take an average of a point layer attribute for points falling within a set of polygons.

After running the algorithm a temporary layer is added which includes the same polygons and fields, but all values are NULL. I've confirmed that both the points and polygon inputs are the same projection (EPSG:4326). When the algorithm runs the only error I see is `"ERROR: Colum <Area_number> not found in table"`.

The field `"Area_number"` belongs to the points layer which is to be averaged, but I've confirmed that this field is in the points layer (selected from the layer in the dialogue for the algorithm). What seems to be the issue here?

I've included the output from v.vect.stats algorithm:

```
QGIS version: 3.14.15-Pi
QGIS code revision: d5114d2cfa
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 3.0.4
GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'v.vect.stats' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : False, 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'areas' : 'C:/Users/pbreach/OneDrive - Golder Associates/Documents/Capstone WSP Project/OneDrive/Claresholm_2021/Mapping/fire_count.shp', 'count_column' : 'Area_Count', 'method' : 1, 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'points' : 'delimitedtext://file:///C:/Users/pbreach/OneDrive%20-%20Golder%20Associates/Documents/Capstone%20WSP%20Project/OneDrive/Data_raw/Wildfires%201983-2018.csv?type=csv&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=Long&yField=Lat&zField=Area%20(ha)&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no', 'points_column' : 'Area_number', 'stats_column' : 'Area_Avg', 'type' : [0] }

g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="C:\Users\pbreach\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_rmCeUm\1487b52b6c59425da32db59cf3e41649\points.shp" output="vector_6130ca8f0d3268" --overwrite -o
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="C:\Users\pbreach\OneDrive - Golder Associates\Documents\Capstone WSP Project\OneDrive\Claresholm_2021\Mapping\fire_count.shp" output="vector_6130ca8f0d3269" --overwrite -o
g.region n=60.0733 s=48.926218554 e=-109.9338 w=-120.2418
v.vect.stats points=vector_6130ca8f0d3268 areas=vector_6130ca8f0d3269 type="point" method="average" points_column=Area_number count_column="Area_Count" stats_column="Area_Avg" --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="auto" input="vector_6130ca8f0d3269" output="C:/Users/pbreach/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_rmCeUm/b0afe63ab06e48cd9cc6c90afec2cca3/output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
C:\Users\pbreach\OneDrive - Golder Associates\Documents
Starting GRASS GIS...
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
Cleaning up temporary files...
Executing <C:\Users\pbreach\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_rmCeUm\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14>g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14>v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="C:\Users\pbreach\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_rmCeUm\1487b52b6c59425da32db59cf3e41649\points.shp" output="vector_6130ca8f0d3268" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Check if OGR layer <points> contains polygons...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Creating attribute table for layer <points>...
Column name <Area (ha)> renamed to <Area__ha_>
Column name <Start Date> renamed to <Start_Date>
Importing 43541 features (OGR layer <points>)...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Building topology for vector map <vector_6130ca8f0d3268@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
10000..20000..30000..40000..
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14>v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="C:\Users\pbreach\OneDrive - Golder Associates\Documents\Capstone WSP Project\OneDrive\Claresholm_2021\Mapping\fire_count.shp" output="vector_6130ca8f0d3269" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Check if OGR layer <fire_count> contains polygons...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Creating attribute table for layer <fire_count>...
Importing 256 features (OGR layer <fire_count>)...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Registering primitives...
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning polygons
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking polygons...
Breaking polygons (pass 1: select break points)...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
Breaking polygons (pass 2: break at selected points)...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking boundaries...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning boundaries at nodes...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Merging boundaries...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing dangles...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Building areas...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..-----------------------------------------------------
Removing bridges...
44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Registering primitives...
Building areas...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Attaching islands...
0..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Finding centroids for OGR layer <fire_count>...
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Writing centroids...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
256 input polygons
Total area: 3.19453E+010 (256 areas)
-----------------------------------------------------
Copying features...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Building topology for vector map <vector_6130ca8f0d3269@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
Building areas...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Attaching islands...
0..100
Attaching centroids...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14>g.region n=60.0733 s=48.926218554 e=-109.9338 w=-120.2418
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14>v.vect.stats points=vector_6130ca8f0d3268 areas=vector_6130ca8f0d3269 type="point" method="average" points_column=Area_number count_column="Area_Count" stats_column="Area_Avg" --overwrite
ERROR: Column <Area_number> not found in table <vector_6130ca8f0d3268>
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14>v.out.ogr type="auto" input="vector_6130ca8f0d3269" output="C:/Users/pbreach/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_rmCeUm/b0afe63ab06e48cd9cc6c90afec2cca3/output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
Exporting 256 areas (may take some time)...
5..11..17..23..29..35..41..47..53..59..65..71..77..83..89..95..100
v.out.ogr complete. 256 features (Polygon type) written to <vector_6130ca8f0d3269> (GPKG format).
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14>exit
Execution of <C:\Users\pbreach\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_rmCeUm\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> finished.
Cleaning up default sqlite database ...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Execution completed in 8.23 seconds
Results:
{'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'v.vect.stats' finished
```

Comment: Could you share a sample of data producing this problem?

Comment: I'd double check that the column is actually "Area_number" and not "Area_Number" all the other column names seem to follow that pattern.